# Sync Drupal 7 calendar with facebook birthdays

Tags: facebook, drupal, drupal-7, calendar

I am using a Drupal 7.15 in my application and I have calendar module and events_calendar used to display the calendar and add and edit events.

I have a requirement of importing/synching facebook birthdays in this calendar.

I have used the below code to get the birthdays from facebook and i am able to get the raw data,

```
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
. "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
. "&code=" . $code;
$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday&".$access_token;
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
```

but how can i **display this in my calendar as an event**?

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, the events in your Drupal site are actually regular nodes with date fields attached, so to have them appear in your site calendar, you need to create them first.

Seeing that you already have some PHP code ready, you could use a function like **node_add()** to generate the nodes, but this gets pretty messy soon; especially if you need to run the script at certain intervals without creating duplicates etc.

I propose using the [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) for this usecase. It can handle JSON data (with an [extra module](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_jsonpath_parser)) and was built exactly for purposes like this. Just note that for synching you calendar, you need to run the synching at certain intervals via cron jobs.